# How to print 1 to 10 with following format first line 1 2nd line 2 & 3 3rd line 4,5 & 6 4th line 7,8,9,10?

Tags: java, loops

I tried like this,

```
 for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
                if (k <= j) {
                    System.out.print(k + " ");
                } else
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

but it prints like

```
1
1 2 
1 2 3  
1 2 3 4
```

This question is asked in one interview i had attended, my mind is breaking to find solution.. i can't think..

Comment: `break` will break from the external `for`..

Comment: my mind is blowed up trying understanding the title of this "question..?"

Comment: thanks for your response but break will not break external for loop ..

Comment: 'break 2' will break external for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

init a variable before

```
int printed = 1;
```

and change your

```
System.out.print(k+" ");
```

with

```
System.out.print(printed+" ");
printed++;
```

Comment: thanks @RamonBoza your solution is correct. that is very simple answer .. now i am relax..

Comment: btw it is an ugly solution, in a future this code will smell badly

Answer (score 1):

This will do it :

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       int i, j, k;
       for (i = 1, j = 1; i < 11; j++)
       {
           for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
           {
               System.out.print(i++ + " ");
           }

           System.out.println();

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do that:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 1, j = 1; i < 11; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
        System.out.print(i++ + " ");
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Basically, i controls the next number to print, and j controls how many numbers you will print in the current line. k is just a counter for j.

Comment: wow..!  this is another way for that i can't believe i am really not thinking at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this with some mathematic magic (sequences).

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
    for (int k=(int) (0.5*(Math.pow(j,2)-j+2));k<=(int) (0.5*j*(j+1));k++) {
         System.out.print(k + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```